# Doctrine nodename nor servname provided, or not known on Docker

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, docker, symfony4

I'm trying to setup the Symfony4 project on Docker, everything is working except Doctrine CLI functions. It seems that it can't connect to database when I run commands via CLI. phpMyAdmin and project itself connects to DB just fine.

Error I get when I run command:

```
php bin/console doctrine:migrations:diff
```

> PDO::__construct(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed:
>   nodename nor servname provided, or not known

Here is my docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3'
services:
    apache:
        build: .docker/apache
        container_name: sf4_apache
        ports:
          - 80:80
        volumes:
          - .docker/config/vhosts:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled
          - .:/home/wwwroot/sf4
        depends_on:
          - php

    mysql:
      image: mysql
      command: "--default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password"
      container_name: sf4_mysql
      restart: always
      volumes:
        - ./data/db/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
      environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
        MYSQL_DATABASE: sf4
        MYSQL_USER: sf4
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: sf4

    php:
        build: .docker/php
        container_name: sf4_php
        volumes:
          - .:/home/wwwroot/sf4
        environment:
          - maildev_host=sf4_maildev
        depends_on:
          - maildev
          - mysql
        links:
          - mysql

    phpmyadmin:
      image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
      container_name: sf4_phpmyadmin
      environment:
        PMA_HOST: mysql
        PMA_PORT: 3306
      ports:
        - 8080:80
      links:
        - mysql

    maildev:
        image: djfarrelly/maildev
        container_name: sf4_maildev
        ports:
          - 8001:80
```

And doctrine.yaml:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        # configure these for your database server
        driver: 'pdo_mysql'
        server_version: '8.0.15'
        charset: utf8mb4
        default_table_options:
            charset: utf8mb4
            collate: utf8mb4_unicode_ci

        url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'
```

Database URL in .env file is:

`DATABASE_URL=mysql://root:root@mysql:3306/sf4`

I tried to change mysql to localhost or IP address for DATABASE_URL config but it didn't helped. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that I was running the CLI command from my computer's command line. So first I had to connect into my Docker container using

```
docker-compose exec php bash
```

And then all the commands runs just fine. :)